# How do I cancel pending MouseEvents on a Sprite?

Tags: actionscript-3, displayobject

I am working at a game where the user interacts with a multitude of elements.

At one point or another the game pauses or stops and breaks the user's interactivity.

I would like to break mouse down and roll over or such things but can't figure out how.

I can't remove the events from the sprite because I would have to do it for all events in all places in all sprites :| Anybody with a smarter solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for you, to disable MouseEvents. Easiest is to set `myGameContainer.mouseChildren = false` or `myInteractiveComponentWithListeners.mouseEnabled=false`

Or you can create transparent Sprite and place it over UI components to block them.

Comment: So I would do mouseChildren = false and the imediately mouseChildren = true? Hmm. I should do mouseEnabled = false then true in case its a Sprite with graphics drawn in it, huh?

Comment: Yes, if you want enable your container with mouse enabled components, you simply set `mouseChildren = true`. Or you can directly disable/enable components by `mouseEnabled = true|false` ;) If there is no graphics in the Sprite, It can't receive any MouseEvents, so this fact shouldn't bother you.

Comment: Cool, I will do some tests tonight and get back to you.